# Erro ao se conectar com sqlite no laravel

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.4

Internamente todos está funcionando, `migrations`, `tinker`, `sqlite3`, porém na aplicação do servidor ele sempre consulta o `mysql` em vez do `sqlite` para todas as operações, ou seja ele está usando `Connector.php` em vez de `SQLiteConnector.php`

há outro tipo de configuração para se conectar com `sqlite`?

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
#DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
#DB_PORT=3306
#DB_DATABASE=./database/database.sqlite
#DB_USERNAME=homestead
#DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**database.php**

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

**Erro**

> QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Nenhuma conex�o p�de ser feita porque a m�quina de destino as recusou ativamente.

Comment: coloque todo o arquivo `database.php`

Comment: "porém na aplicação do servidor" o que você está rodando lá? existem alguma env var já definida? Env vars tem prioridade sob o arquivo .env

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o arquivo não foi mexido, somente 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite') coloquei para ver se funcionava mas não deu certo

Comment: @gmsantos creio que não tenha pois startei o servidor e mais nada, na verdade vou ver do que se trata essas env vars

Comment: poste o erro exato que está acontecendo

Comment: editei a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Erro era bobo, simplesmente tinha 2 servidores startados, não deixando assim as configurações serem refletidas na aplicação